# How to extract string between "+" and "@" from column in Presto?

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I have table in Presto like below:

**Input data:**

```
PHONE_NUMBER
--------
ppa:+77845678021@abc.gbc443.gbc356.7kffooopppp.deu  
tel:+77695002395  
dadsadas+884415002996xx2
....
```

**Requirements:**

And I need to take all values from column "PHONE_NUMBER" between "+" and "@" (if exists).

**Desire output:**

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
PHONE_NUMBER
--------
77845678021 
77695002395 
884415002996
....
```

How can I do that in Presto ?

Comment: Your third row doesn't have a `@`, but you still extracting not till the end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for this version of a question you could use something like this:

```sql
SELECT regexp_extract(PHONE_NUMBER, '\+(\d+)@?', 1) from my_table;
```

Here from `PHONE_NUMBER` of every row will be extracted digits, that immediately follow plus sign, and optionally followed by `@`.

If you has some understanding of how much digits is expected, you could use `\+(\d{13,146})@?`, where 13 - minimum number of digits (including), 146 - maximum (including).

Comment: markelex, I used your code and I have ERROR like: DatabaseError: {'message': 'target of repeat operator is not specified', 'errorCode': 7, 'errorName': 'INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT'

Comment: @dingaro, my bad. Try `\+(\d+)@?`

Comment: wow! It works correct, thank you very much I spent all day on that - I gave best answer :)